# upload frames to cloud and show though an app in python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, cloud, object-detection

i need help in my task which i have to complete in a day. i need to upload key frames in a cloud database and if possible, show monitoring through an app. The key frames should be generated through an object detection (The frames which detected an object, only that should be stored in cloud) i have done this part, i am stuck at the cloud thing. Which cloud should be used how to store key frames there and how to monitor through an app in python code. if anyone could understand and can help i will be very appreciate. Thanks

Comment: You need all this done today? First step is going to be going back in time a few days. Alternatively, you could talk to the stakeholder about extending the deadline.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have to submit on Sunday besides if i can get help and learn this thing it would be appreciated

Comment: Please read the help section of this forum for what are appropriate questions and how to ask a good question. Your question is too broad and asking for opinions.